# How to connect backyard cover to existing roof?

Tags: roof, gutters, backyard, cover

This is an image I found on the internet

[image]

My roof in the backyard is very similar where it sloping down toward the yard. I want to make the cover like the photo.

Few questions:

1. From the photo, look like they put the new roof of the cover ON TOP of the existing roof? How does water get run off?
2. Is the gutter still there under the new roof of the cover?
3. How to do this correctly? I am not sure if the photo shows a correct way of doing this.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

**Option 1:**

I like the glass design. But thinking of using lumber instead of metal frame. Look like this will require cutting into the existing overhang. I also saw a little pipe pointing to the left side. How does the water escaping out of there? Also it seems "flat".

[image]

**Option 2:**

This option seems "correct" in term of slope and water escape. But how do I frame the "white triangle" portion below the patio? Is it just siding material?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The photo does indeed show the patio cover extending up over the existing roof. This is not the normal way to do this sort of thing but apparently had to be done that way because there was next to no clearance between the tops of the windows and the existing roof overhang to attach a more conventional ledger board onto the side of the house. With the conventional ledger board it would be screwed into the wall studs and then the rafters of the patio cover would attach to the ledger using hanger brackets.

Using the method showing in the picture it is necessary to open up the existing roof covering so that the upper ends of the cover rafters can be tapered and fastened down to the roof structure. The the roofing material of the cover is installed followed by replacement covering of the existing roof overlapping the upper end of the cover material. Sometimes the cover rafters may even be extended and nailed to the sides of the existing roof rafters. Doing this requires removing the sheathing of the existing roof at the point where the join is made.

In that picture, the roof of the house is so flat that it is possible that they extended the roofing material of the patio cover all the way to the ridge of the house roof.

Comment: My other question is that now the water from existing can go down the cover rafter and then straight down on either side (left, front, right). There is no gutter attached to that patio cover. I mean "is that right?". How does the rain water being managed here?

Comment: I guess you get to decide. Place gutters where they are needed.

Comment: I have updated with two options so I am wondering what your opinions are on those. I would like to design something that last a long time and properly built. Let's say if I hire a home inspector to look at, it should be approved.